# Are the TeX Gyre fonts designed to match each other?

Tags: fonts, typography

I'm currently testing out some fonts and found out that some fonts are designed to match each other (good serif+sans-serif+typewriter combinations).

**Are the TeX Gyre fonts, which provide at leats one for each type (serif, sans-serif, typewriter) are designed to be used together?**

Comment: no, they are the modified OTF versions of the URW Type 1 variants and, of course, _with_ corresponding math fonts.

Comment: @Herbert The Font Catalogue lists them without math support. And the TeX Gyre Pagella Math and the TeX Gyre Termes Math (the only two TeX Gyre with math support yet) don't work with `pdfLaTeX` (which I'm using).

Comment: @FooBar No-one is going to create new TeX-only math fonts: if you want matching math support you need to go with one of the small set that already exist for (pdf)TeX.

Comment: especially the TeX Gyre Pagella is not the same if you use pdflatex or xelatex. See a previous question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101019/no-old-style-numbers-with-small-caps-and-tgpagella

Comment: @FooBar: Sure, if you want all the new features you have to use the OpenType variants.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the sake of closing the question, here is a summary of the comments:

> No, the TeX Gyre fonts are not meant to be used together. They are just a high quality Type1 and OpenType replacement of standard fonts that used to be provided by the URW collection in Type1.

The [TeX Gyre](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/) collection of fonts consists of:

```
TeX Gyre font        Original font             Old URW replacement font
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TeX Gyre Adventor    ITC Avant Garde Gothic    URW Gothic L
TeX Gyre Bonum       ITC Bookman               URW Bookman L
TeX Gyre Chorus      ITC Zapf Chancery         URW Chancery L Medium Italic
TeX Gyre Cursor      Courier                   URW Nimbus Mono L
TeX Gyre Heros       Helvetica                 URW Nimbus Sans L
TeX Gyre Pagella     Palatino                  URW Palladio L
TeX Gyre Schola      Century Schoolbook        URW Century Schoolbook L
TeX Gyre Termes      Times (New) Roman         URW Nimbus Roman No9 L
```

As the original fonts that the TeX Gyre collection replaces were not designed to be used together, the TeX Gyre fonts themselves can't be expected to be designed for that purpose.

Comment: So what are the recommanded sans and mono fonts if I want to typeset my document in Tex Gyre Pagella or TeX Gyre Termes. My natural approach would have been to use Tex Gyre Heros and Tex Gyre Cursor.

Comment: @MaxNoe I have found Gillius to be a satisfactory companion for TeX Gyre Termes.